# WebLogic uses strange time zone and always recompiles JSPs

Tags: jsp, weblogic

I have problem that WebLogic always recompiles my JSPs even if don't change them.
I found out that after compilation my JSP have following code:

```
public static boolean _staticIsStale(weblogic.servlet.jsp.StaleChecker sci) {
    if (sci.isResourceStale("/pages/manDispatchOverview.jsp", 1434357476000L ,"10.3.6.0","GMT")) return true;
    if (sci.isResourceStale("/pages_include/allowDownloadChecker.jspf", 1433929740000L ,"10.3.6.0","GMT")) return true;
    if (sci.isResourceStale("/beans/help_key.jspf", 1434130922000L ,"10.3.6.0","GMT")) return true;
    if (sci.isResourceStale("/beans/status_image.jspf", 1434130928000L ,"10.3.6.0","GMT")) return true;
    if (sci.isResourceStale("/contextMenu.jsp", 1434130938000L ,"10.3.6.0","GMT")) return true;
```

I was very confused when I saw GMT time zone because I use `-Duser.timezone='Europe/Warsaw'` parameter to specify correct time zone.

Any idea why WebLogic uses wrong time zone and always recompile my JSPs?

Additional hints:

- I don't set parameters `pageCheckSeconds` and `servet-reload-check-secs`
- My server runs in debugging mode
- I deploy my application as explode EAR and WAR.

Comment: Where are you setting `-Duser.timezone=<timezone>` https://blogs.oracle.com/wlscoherence/entry/time_zone_on_weblogic_server ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using node manager to start the manage servers?if yes then also add time zone parameter using JAVA_OPTIONS in startnodemanager.sh .Also timezone should be set in setDomainEnv.sh so that it will get applied on admin as well as managed server.After setting all parameters as above restart  admin,node manager and managed server and check logs and confirm that there is no GMT timezone present anywhere.

Comment: No, I'm not using node manager? And I don't see any place where GMT is set.